# How to let admob comes after a specific delay time?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, admob, ionic2

Is there any way to set delay first time arrived for admob in ionic 2?

I need to set the delay since I do not want to let my user fill annoyed due to advertisement.

Let say after 60 seconds, then it  would be nice admob show up on my app.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using [`cordova plugin add cordova-admob`](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/) then you could set a timeout to start showing the ads:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

  // Set AdMobAds options:
  admob.setOptions({
    publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",
  });

  // Start showing banners (atomatic when autoShowBanner is set to true)
  setTimeout(admob.createBannerView, 60000);
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Be careful not doing so with interstitials as AdMob team may ban your app due to [Interstitials that unexpectedly launch](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en):

> **Interstitials that unexpectedly launch**
>
> Don't surprise users with interstitial ads. Placing interstitial ads
>   so that they suddenly appear when a user is focused on a task at hand
>   (e.g. playing a game, filling out a form, reading content) may lead to
>   accidental clicks and often creates a frustrating user experience. For
>   this reason, interstitial ads should only be implemented at logical
>   breaks in between your app's content (e.g. pages, stages, or levels)
>   to ensure that the user is prepared to engage with the ad.
>
> A common issue is that even though you may intend for the ad to load
>   in between page content, the ad itself appears shortly after a new
>   page of content has loaded due to carrier latency. To prevent this
>   from happening, we recommend you pre-load the interstitial in advance.